# How do I place the Date and Time on my horizontal axis to be in separate rows in a figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot

I am plotting a graph of random data versus datetime strings.  These datetime strings are all in one line and serve as labels on the horizontal axis.  I would like the date to be displayed in one line and the time to be in another line.

The image below describes my graph.  I would like the time to be displayed underneath the date.

[image]

The code I used to generate the graph is shown below:

```
figure
plot(sample(:,1),sample(:,2:5),'o')
tick=get(gca,'xtick');
set(gca,'xticklabel',datestr(tick,31))
drawnow()
```

How can I get the time of each horizontal label to appear below the date?

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote to generate this graph?

Comment: @rayryeng Added my code to the post..How can I set the graph to my requirement ?

Comment: wrote an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can introduce the TeX command [`\newline`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102143-how-do-i-get-a-new-line-with-the-text-function-using-tex-formatting-in-matlab-7-2-r2006a) inside the date string in between the spaces of the date and the time, then set these new strings to be the `X` Tick labels in your figure.  You'll need to convert the character array that is output from `datestr` into a cell array of strings with [`cellstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html), then use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to perform the replacement from a space to `\newline`.

Something like this should work:

```
figure
plot(sample(:,1),sample(:,2:5),'o')
tick=get(gca,'xtick');
vals = cellstr(datestr(tick,31)); %// Change
new_vals = strrep(vals, ' ', '\newline'); %// New
set(gca,'xticklabel',new_vals); %// Change
drawnow()
```

When I do this with a sample plot:

```
plot(1:6, 1:6, 'r.');
```

I get this as the final result once I run the code:

[image]

Take note that this assumes that the `X` Ticks are sufficiently spaced apart from each other.  Your plot will look cluttered if you have many ticks on the horizontal axis.

Comment: When we are using strrep,  It's just printing the string '\newline' between the date and time rather than going to next line.

Comment: @MaK What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I gave a try in 2012b. But, I am working the code with 2015a. At this moment, not having the higher version with me.

Comment: @MaK Ah I see.  This code works for me and I'm running R2015a.  I'll look for a workaround for lower versions in any case.

Comment: Super, then this work for me as well. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MaK You're very welcome!  I'll still look for a way that supports lower versions of MATLAB, but this should definitely work in R2015a.